# jquery background image stretches across screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i know there are a number of plugins that can do this, i have tried a few. in the past the ones i have tried always lead to some flickering on Firefox.

The one in the link below seems to work seamlessly, but i cant seem to figure out what they are using.

if anyone can take a look, i'd appreciate it!

link: http://usa.buy2.co.il/assets/themes/Buy2Usa/pages/error.html

thanks!

Comment: Seconded... All I can see there is a page that looks like the background is set to position:fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accomplish this with CSS.

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

[Go here to learn more](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)